# How can I root to a folder with no specific name?

Tags: php

I need to make this:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/house/city1/content.php');
```

to something like this:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/house/../content.php');
```

Because 'city1' is always different but I dont want to change it in all single files.

I already tried

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/house/../content.php');
```

but it is not working.

How can I make this work?

Comment: In directory structures .. goes up one level. It's not a placeholder or token for an unknown value in the middle of a directory structure. 

Without seeing more code or understanding the structure of your project there's not enough here to go on to help you. 

Do the files with this include() statement know which city1 or equivalent content.php file they need to load?

Comment: The thing is that in 'content.php' are seperated parts which are always the same but one part with prices have to be different for each city.. so I thought I could root to the price part in the folder but still have one content.php file to add or remove something in the future. I could make it work right now already but it would be 'content1.php' (rooted) then 'price.php' (not rooted) and 'content2.php' (rooted) again ..

Comment: I think I understand - I've popped a suggestion into an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment I would suggest you're creating extra work having lots of similar content.php files.

I would consider updating your content.php so that it can handle the varying prices in one file.

Then:

```
$price_set = 1; // Change this line for each variant of pricing
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/house/content.php'); // Ensure this path is the correct one to the now global content.php
```

Within your content.php where you want to show the prices you can then just do some conditions to show the right prices..:

```
if(isset($price_set) && $price_set == 1) {
  // set the right pricing info here
}
```

Or it may be you have so many variations that an array/database lookup for the right $price_set to be shown.

Comment: so this would work?: if(isset($price_set) && $price_set == 1) {
 include...
}

Comment: It absolutely should if you'd rather include another file inside that conditional.